# How to use my react native apk with different wifi ip?

Tags: php, android, sql-server, reactjs, react-native

I developed my react native application with PHP backend and sql Server .

My actual problem is : I can't use my application (for example my login page is connected with php page so once I press connexion button I use fuction that fetch (http:192.168.1.2:80/fetch.php) 
but this url is related to wifi so if I am at home I shoud change it to 192.168.1.4 
and this is the reason why my app doesn't work if I change wifi )

I hope you understand my problem and I am waiting for your help to work with my apk in any place and wifi

Comment: Do you have any reason why the php backend server can't have the same ip?
I mean, just set your php server to `192.168.1.2` seems to be the easiest.

Comment: I cant because the ip is ip4 of wifi so if i am using diff places i should change it . I don't know if there  an ip common to use it everywhere

Comment: Well, another way is to create a digital ocean droplet (or whatever brand you like) and host your php backend there. Since it's on the public internet, you can access it from anywhere without changing the ip.